# How to force a linebreak in itemization?

Tags: lists, line-breaking, itemize

I have a proposition which consists of two itemized bullets. I want both to be displayed in an offset way, but the first one keeps getting displayed as a continuation of the Proposition in bold.

How to get what I want?

This is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{url}
\title{whatever}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\begin{document}
\begin{prop}
This is the usual display.
\end{prop}
\begin{prop}
\label{prop:twocases}
\begin{itemize}
\mbox{} \item If $b_{1} \leq \sqrt{x}$, then: $\epsilon_{i}=\epsilon_{i}^{+}, i
\in \{1,2,3\}.$
\item If $b_{1} > \sqrt{x}$, then either $\epsilon_{i}=\epsilon_{i}^{+}, i \in
\{1,2,3\}$ or $\epsilon_{i}=\epsilon_{i}^{-}, i \in \{1,2,3\}.$
\end{itemize}
\end{prop}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How is the `prop` environment defined? If it's defined with the `ntheorem` package, you could insert the instruction `\theoremstyle{break}` prior to `prop` getting set up; this will force a line break after `Proposition <num>`.

Comment: But I don't want a linebreak every time. I guess I could define two separate prop environments, but it's rather awkward. Thanks anyway. Other ideas?

Comment: you can use `\mbox{}\begin{itemize....` as a quick workaround

Comment: Hi! It does move the first bullet like I wanted, but now the Proposition is also moved! How to get the benefit without the side-effect? Thanks!

Comment: if you're using `amsthm`, insert `\leavevmode` before the list.  (this may allow a page break between the proposition heading and the list if you're unlucky.  we're working on that problem.)

Comment: @FelixGoldberg moved where? Please (for any question) make a complete document that may be run that shows the problem, and all packages required to reproduce.

Comment: Felix, I've edited your question to include the document from your comment. You may have been able to do that yourself, but regardless, there it is.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Thanks for the edit. It's so much easier to answer questions with a supplied MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the `\mbox{}` in the wrong place:

```
 \mbox{}\begin{itemize}
```

Is where it should go.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `\mbox{}\begin{itemize}` caused too much of a gap so I defined a new command

```
\newcommand{\gap}{\mbox{}\vspace{-5mm}}
```

to put before the `\begin{itemize}`. This enabled me to regulate how much space I wanted (I found this was about enough just to skip down a line).

It's a pretty crude way of doing stuff but it worked well for me since I only wanted to do it for a few of my definitions and didn't want to define a new theoremstyle as I wanted to keep the counter going for my definitions.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)